# Detect triangles an rectangles from image with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, geometry

I have this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAIoK.jpg):

And i want take out the triangle and rectangles from the image. I have 2 algorithmes, one for triangles and another for rectangles in the code below. But they are very similar. But in this way i only can take out the triangle more bright.  Can anyone help me please.

```
IplImage* DetectAndDrawTriang(IplImage* img){
    CvSeq* contours;
    CvSeq* result;
    CvMemStorage *storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    int d=30;

    IplImage* ret = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 3);
    IplImage* temp = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvSet(ret,cvScalar(0,0,0));
    cvCvtColor(img, temp, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvThreshold( temp, temp, 180, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );
    //cvSmooth(temp, temp, CV_GAUSSIAN, 9, 9, 0,0);
    cvNamedWindow("thre");
    cvShowImage("thre", temp);

    cvFindContours(temp, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));

    while(contours)
    {
        result = cvApproxPoly(contours, sizeof(CvContour), storage, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter(contours)*0.1, 0);
        if(result->total==3)
        {
            CvPoint *pt[3];
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                pt[i] = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i);


            if((int)sqrt((pt[0]->x-pt[2]->x)*(pt[0]->x-pt[2]->x)+(pt[0]->y-pt[2]->y)*(pt[0]->y-pt[2]->y))>=d && (int)sqrt((pt[0]->x-pt[1]->x)*(pt[0]->x-pt[1]->x)+(pt[0]->y-pt[1]->y)*(pt[0]->y-pt[1]->y))>=d && (int)sqrt((pt[1]->x-pt[2]->x)*(pt[1]->x-pt[2]->x)+(pt[1]->y-pt[2]->y)*(pt[1]->y-pt[2]->y))>=d)
            {
                cvLine(ret, *pt[0], *pt[1], cvScalar(255,255,255));

                cvLine(ret, *pt[1], *pt[2], cvScalar(255,255,255));

                cvLine(ret, *pt[2], *pt[0], cvScalar(255,255,255));
            }
        }
        contours = contours->h_next;
    }

    cvReleaseImage(&temp);
    cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);

    return ret;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by take out?

Comment: Put in another image only the triangles and rectangles. Sorry for my english :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Idea I can think of is using the cv::matchShapes function (I suggest using the cv2 library with Mat instead of Ipl images). matchShapes takes a Mat of the object you want to detect and a Mat of the object you want to compare it against. So in your case you can make a Mat of the contours of a triangle and square and compare those images with each contour in the image your are searching through.

You may also consider simply doing template matching since your objects are static. Check out cv::matchTemplate and its pretty much the same idea as the above paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Right now i'll stick with the IplImage since i am not a great c++ master. And it will make me a lot of confusing change my code i made the last months.. I think i will try python in a couple of months insted of c++.
I dont think cv::matchTemplate will work since my code have to detect the triangles and rectangles in diferent images, sizes and gray colors.
What i ended to do was the same of my original code but i used cvInRangeS, cvFindContours and cvApproxPoly. It worked, but it will not work with if the gray colors of the objetcs change.

Answer (score 0):

ApproxPoly is a good solution **if** you can be sure that your contours are complete.
If the contour is a square but doesn't close then it will be a line with four segments and 3 corners after approximating.

Another solution is to fit a box around the contour points (there is a function to do this) and check the width/height ratio. You can then test the individual line segments in the contour list to see if they match the box sides.

Comment: You are right. Thats a problem.
What i ended to do is in my reply of Eddie E Massey III abose